# JDO Datanucleus: Annotator @Column(jdbcType="") not working

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I noticed that this type of annotation does not work. 
In my example I had set:

```
      @Column(jdbcType="VARCHAR(5)")
      private String id;
```

but in the db saves me how: VARCHAR(255).

How can I fix?

Comment: [Reference JDO](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/annotations.html#Column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
@Column(jdbcType="VARCHAR", length=5)
private String id;
```

From the documentation here: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/annotations.html#Column

Comment: thank you! but if you wanted jdbcType is LONGTEXT? I tried to insert it but it always saves as varchar!

Comment: Try using the `sqlType` property in this case.